# Query lastest Relationship, When Account was Created

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables: `Account` and `Transaction`.

These tables relate to each other, by `Account` **hasOne** `Transaction`.

i want to show `data` in `Transaction` page, once `Account` was created.

**My Account Model**

```
    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\App\Transaction::class)->latest();
    }
```

**My Transaction Model**

```
    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Account::class);
    }
```

**And my TransactionController**

(I tried to implement code like below, but still no luck):

```
   public function index()
    {
        $transactions = Transaction::with(['account' => function($query) {
                        $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
                    }]);

        return response()->json(['transactions' => $transactions]);
    }
```

Any Help? Thanks.....

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to sort the transactions by when the account was created, or sort the accounts attached to the transaction based on when they account was created? It seems like this is a one to one relationship and the latter wouldn't make sense but I want to be sure

Comment: If your `Account` only has one `Transaction`, why is the function called `transactions()`? Also, you wouldn't use `latest()` (or any other sorting logic) as **there would only be one record**... This is quite confusing. I think you might have an issue with your database structure; I would expect that an `Account` would have many `Transaction` records, and each `Transaction` would belong to an `Account` (that part seems fine already).

Comment: @TimLewis sorry ma bad, i will correct this...

Comment: @AlecJoy yeah, its `one-to-one` relationship.

Comment: @TimLewis i corrected the relationship, still i cant see any data when `account` was created.

Comment: Okay, so you have a one to one relationship between `Transaction` and `Account`, what is the piece of data that you're missing? The `created_at` for the account? Or are you trying to sort the transaction

Comment: @AlecJoy My Purpose is, showing `Account data` in `Transaction` Page When `Account` was created.

Comment: I think I see the problem now, check answers

Comment: remove the `first()` from the constraint, you don't execute a query in the constraint, and this query is to get the account for all the transactions, not one

Comment: @lagbox i cant get `Account` in `Transaction` when `Account` was Created.

Comment: yea I have no idea what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oooopppp i found what i want....**

`In my AccountController`

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validateData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'code' => 'required',
        ]);
        $account = new Account();
        $account->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $account->code = $request->code;
        $account->name = $request->name;
        $account->description = $request->description;
        $account->balance = $request->balance;
        $account->save();

        $transaction = new \App\Transaction();
        $transaction->credit = $request->balance;
        $account->transaction()->save($transaction);

        return response()->json(['created' => true]);
    }
```

i have to save `Transaction` Relationship with `Account`.

Answer (score 0):

QueryBuilder chains need either a get() or a first() or something of that nature at the end to execute the query, right now the variable you're passing to the view is the unexecuted query builder. Try this

```
$transactions = Transaction::with(['account' => function($query) {
    $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')
}])->get();
```

Although, as TimLewis pointed out in the comments, if the relationship between transactions and accounts is one to one then there's no need to do any ordering of the account so it can just be this

```
$transactions = Transaction::with('account')->get();
```

Comment: sorry, but this isnt what i want. u still dont catch my purpose.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the result? Is there a specific field you need data from?